# standard behavior on char buffer initialization

Tags: c++, char

If I defined a char buffer like below

```
char buffer[20] = "foo";
```

then

```
buffer[0] == 'f';
buffer[1] == 'o';
buffer[2] == 'o';
buffer[3] == 0;
```

What does the standard say about **buffer[4]** to **buffer[19]**. Are they guaranteed to be intialized to zero as well ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All remaining elements guaranteed to be intialized to zero.

Reference:
**C++03 Standard section 6.7.8 para 21:**

> If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be
>   initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of compilers will initialize the content of buffer[20] to 0.  It is especially true if you initialize it with {}

You can check your compiler's behaviour using something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        char buf1[20] = "foo";
        char buf2[20] = {};
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < 21; i++ ) {
                printf("%02x ", buf1[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        for(i = 0; i < 21; i++ ) {
                printf("%02x ", buf2[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
}
```

*Note that i put 21 in the conditional rather than 20 just to push the output beyond the actual buffer allocation. It should dump some garbage byte afterwards.*

Comment: The behavior is **Well Defined** by the C++ Standard(as quoted in the accepted answer).It is not left out as implementation detail of compilers.You can be assured of the behavior you dont need to check it.

Comment: And you can't say what "should" happen if you read beyond the end of the array - that gives undefined behaviour.